# Center of GL(2,F) and SL(2,F)

Tags: group-theory

My question is to find the center of GL(2,F) and SL(2,F) where $F=\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C}$

My attempt:

Generalising the identity element, if we take $\pmatrix{ a& 0\\\ 0& a}$. Then these elements commute with every 2x2 matrix irrespective of which $F$ we take.

So is it safe to say that these are in center of all these groups?

Comment: Yes for $F=\mathbb{C}$, but this needs a proof :).

Comment: even if F=Z then too this will be center

Comment: Sure, but that's just restating the definition of the center, and you also haven't proved that every central element is of that form.

Comment: @Foggy : However you need to be careful that $\pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}$ is not in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but does commute with all the matrices of the latter.

Comment: @ThibautDumont why not

Comment: $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is defined to be the set of matrices $g$ with integer coefficients such that $det(g)\in \mathbb{Z}^*=\{\pm 1\}$. This is to ensure that the inverse is again in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. But the inverse of $diag(2,2)$ is $diag(1/2,1/2)$.